# expanding ~ inside .bashrc

Tags: bash

I need to expand the home folder inside **.bashrc** as in the following example:

```
HOME=~
export ANT_OPTS=-Dant.logger.defaults=$HOME/environment/AnsiColorLogger.override
```

Is there a shortcut to do it in one line without the throw-away HOME variable?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`HOME` is already a built-in variable in bash; in fact, its value is what `~` expands to.

From the bash man page:

> HOME
>
> The home directory of the current user; the default argument
>   for the cd builtin command.  The value of this variable is also used
>   when performing tilde expansion.